# How do i fix this python class name error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, knn

In creating a class for KNN I have these 2 different functions "predict_new_item" and "get_ids_of_k_closest" Ive created a variable called "closestK" and set this equal to get_ids_of_k_closest however python is throwing me a name error saying

"'get_ids_of_k_closest' is not defined"

```
def predict_new_item(self, newItem):
    """make prediction for single item. Step 1 is same as 1-NN steps 2 and 3 need writing"""

    distFromNewItem = np.zeros((self.numTrainingItems))

    for stored_example in range(self.numTrainingItems-1):
        distFromNewItem[stored_example] = self.distance(newItem, self.modelX[stored_example])
        closestK = get_ids_of_k_closest(k, distFromNewItem)
        labelCounts = np.zeros(len(self.labelsPresent))

        for k in range(k-1):
            thisindex = closestK[k]
            self.thislabel = self.y_train[thisindex]
            labelCounts[thisindex]+1
            thisPrediction = np.amax(labelCounts)
        return (thisPrediction)



def get_ids_of_k_closest(distFromNewItem, k):
    closestK = np.empty(k, dtype=int)

    arraySize = len(distFromNewItem.shape[0])

    for k in range(k-1):
        thisClosest = 0
        for exemplar in range(arraySize-1):
            if (distFromNewItem[exemplar] < distFromNewItem[thisClosest]):
                thisClosest = exemplar
                closestK[k] = thisClosest
        distFromNewItem[thisClosest] = 100000
    return (closestK)
```

Added whole class code below for those asking in the comments:

```
class simple_KNN:
def __init__(self, k, verbose=True):
    self.k = k
    self.distance= W7utils.euclidean_distance

    self.verbose = verbose

def fit(self, X, y):
    self.numTrainingItems = X.shape[0]
    self.numFeatures = X.shape[0]
    self.modelX = X
    self.modelY = y
    self.labelsPresent = np.unique(self.modelY)

    if (self.verbose):
        print(
            f"There are {self.numTrainingItems} training examples, each described by values for {self.numFeatures} features")
        print(
            f"So self.modelX is a 2D array of shape {self.modelX.shape}")
        print(
            f"self.modelY is a list with {len(self.modelY)} entries, each being one of these labels {self.labelsPresent}")


def predict(self, newItems):

    numToPredict = newItems.shape[0]
    predictions = np.empty(numToPredict)

    for item in range(numToPredict-1):
        thisPrediction = self.predict_new_item(newItems[item])
        predictions[item] = thisPrediction
    return predictions

def predict_new_item(self, newItem):    
    distFromNewItem = np.zeros((self.numTrainingItems))

    for stored_example in range(self.numTrainingItems-1):
        distFromNewItem[stored_example] = self.distance(newItem,  self.modelX[stored_example])
        closestK = get_ids_of_k_closest(k, distFromNewItem)
        labelCounts = np.zeros(len(self.labelsPresent))

        for k in range(k-1):
            thisindex = closestK[k]
            self.thislabel = self.y_train[thisindex]
            labelCounts[thisindex]+1
            thisPrediction = np.amax(labelCounts)

        return (thisPrediction)

def get_ids_of_k_closest(distFromNewItem, k):
    closestK = np.empty(k, dtype=int)
    arraySize = len(distFromNewItem.shape[0])
    for k in range(k-1):
        thisClosest = 0
        for exemplar in range(arraySize-1):
            if (distFromNewItem[exemplar] < distFromNewItem[thisClosest]):
                thisClosest = exemplar
                closestK[k] = thisClosest
        distFromNewItem[thisClosest] = 100000
    return (closestK)
```

Comment: Can you please show exactly how you are calling get_ids_of_k_closest?

Comment: closestK = get_ids_of_k_closest(k, distFromNewItem)

Comment: and where is the class?

Comment: Added whole class

Comment: Unrelated: Snake case should be used for variables, Pascal case for class names.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't even go there we were given the code to edit and the switching between camel case and Snake case is very frustrating when trying to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

My guess. You are missing a `@staticmethod` and not prefixing the invocation with the class name:

```py
class MyClass:
    def predict_new_item(self, newItem):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_ids_of_k_closest(distFromNewItem, k):
        ...



closestK = MyClass.get_ids_of_k_closest(k, distFromNewItem)
```

Comment: How'd you manage to reverse `k` and `dist_from_new_item` (why are you using camel case) as arguments to the function in just a few lines?

Comment: Could it just not be working because I'm calling another function from inside the class?

Answer (score 0):

Function was inside the class when it should have been outside the class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).